# how to add sparkle plugin to wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

i would like to know how can i add the following plugin to my wordpress site body? in which the sparkle effect is all over the body, something like snowfall effect. beginner in wordpress.

appreciate if anyone can help, thanks.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/04/jquery-canvas-sparkles-plugin/

the link below is a demo, but its only one certain element and it only applies on mouse over.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?DSfgrv5e

Answer (score 1):

It will require some html and javascript knowledge.

View the source code [of the demo page](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-canvas-sparkles/). You need to include the scripts `requestAnimationFrame.js` and `jquery-canvas-sparkles.js` on your server (wordpress should include jquery for you already), and [enqueue them in functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) (from @AJ Zane).

Then, see the `<script>` block below those files in the source code on how to initialize the plugin. You want to add that code as well. Put it in another javascript file and make sure you include it after the original scripts.

To customize the plugin, you'll have to read the documentation and figure out what element selectors to use.

Note: This is a good opportunity to learn how to [make your own plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), if you are interested.

Comment: Instead of adding the <script src=""> to your footer.php file, you should follow WP standards and [enqueue scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your theme's functions.php

Comment: Of course, it was just a hack. I updated it for WordPress enqueue. Though if you are going to do things properly, you may as well go all the way and put this in a plugin.